# Problems copying CodeIgniter Installation

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to copy a CodeIgniter installation using svn to a different, brand new server. I have it checked in (did sudo svn commit -m "Initial commit") on the old box. On the the new one, I ran

```
sudo yum install httpd
sudo yum install php
sudo yum install mysql
```

Started all the services, checked out exactly the same codeigniter installation, in the /var/www/html directory, and only the first index page loads and all the links are broken. I made sure that the .htaccess files in the web root are exactly the same. A 'svn status --verbose' command in the system/application/config directory returns exactly the same version numbers on both boxes. What could be the problem?

Just to clarify what happens, the 'home' pages loads (ex: myurl.com) but when I click on a link, like "About" it loads the correct URL 'myurl.com/about' in my browser, but the browser says the page doesn't exist 'Oops! This link appears to be broken.'.

I have checked the 'svn status' of the controllers folder and the views folder, all the same version numbers. Any advice would be a huge help!

UPDATE: I have found a "base_href" Constant defined in system/applications/config.php, I changed it, but it hasn't made any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a mod_rewrite issue to me - enable mod_rewrite, restart httpd, and see what happens when you click on your link.